# List mercurial checkins for one user

Tags: mercurial

How can I list the checkins for a specific mercurial user using TortoiseHg, or failing that, using hg on the command line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The hg log command has a "user" option (-u or --user). To find my commits, I could do...

```
hg log --user "Mark Hildreth"
```